# train image classification models with colab

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, image-classification

I follow the template and change the link , but it doesn't work
https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification.ipynb#scrollTo=3jz5x0JoskPv

This is my datasets
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lol-fypproject.appspot.com/o/lol.tgz?alt=media&token=d07b81bd-442f-4ebe-920e-3772598fbb20

original code

```
image_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
  'flower_photos.tgz',
  'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',
  extract=True)
 image_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(image_path), 'flower_photos')
```

I changed in that

```
image_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
  'lol.tgz',
  'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lol-fypproject.appspot.com/o/lol.tgz?alt=media&token=d07b81bd-442f-4ebe-920e-3772598fbb20',
  extract=True)
image_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(image_path), 'lol')
```

the line wrong and error message is showed

```
data = ImageClassifierDataLoader.from_folder(image_path)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-a5e7646aca55> in <module>()
----> 1 data = ImageClassifierDataLoader.from_folder(image_path)
  2 train_data, test_data = data.split(0.9)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/data_util/image_dataloader.py 
 in 
 from_folder(cls, filename, shuffle)
 69     all_image_size = len(all_image_paths)
 70     if all_image_size == 0:
 ---> 71       raise ValueError('Image size is zero')
 72 
 73     if shuffle:

 ValueError: Image size is zero
```

Comment: Have you checked if there's a `lol` directory after extracting your `lol.tgz`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the problem

the path of the zip file is not the right structure as the sample

Comment: i'm also struggling with the same URL problem, how did you solve it?